# What is the registry entry made when Microsoft outlook runs for the first time after installation

Tags: outlook, registry

In my application I want to pop up a message when MS Outlook runs for the first time after installation. I need to know what registry key is added when MS Outlook is run for the first time, after a fresh installation.

Comment: I would recommend you export the registry before the installation, then export it again after installation and compare the two. That will help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically Outlook doesn't have any profiles configured when you run it for the first time. So, you may check out the following registry hive for profile entries:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles

Or just take a look at the First-Run value in the following key in Windows Registry:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\Setup